# What is the difference between += and = when changing the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript

Currently taking a course in treehouse on javascript. I understand when the instructor changes the value of a variable with just the = sign. But sometimes the instructor uses += and never really explained why. Im having a hard time understanding the difference between the two signs and on what instance would I use either of them. I would like your input on it to help me better understand, thank you. ie :

```
var message = "hello";
message = "Whats up";
console.log(message);    //Will log: Whats up

var anotherMessage = "Hey";
anotherMessage += "How are you doing?"
console.log(anotherMessage)  //What would happen here, and why?
```

Comment: x = x + y is the same as x += y

Comment: "HeyHow are you doing?"

Comment: [MDN: Addition Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment)

Comment: @JeremyBanks so anotherMessage would log "Hey how are you doing?" while `message = "Whats up";` becomes the new value in message?

Comment: @j08691 I was more interested in the why. thanks for your input though.

Comment: @Walt Yes (though, an extra space won't be included -- `"HeyHow are you doing?"`). The `=` alone simply replaces the value of the variable. The `+=` first retrieves the current value, using it to determine a new result, then assigns that to the variable.

Comment: @GameAlchemist What a constructive message. I'm sure a new user to this site is going to understand *exactly* what you mean, and have no chance of being confused and offended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`.

This operator is called `Addition assignment` by Wikipedia. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B))

**In your case :**

```
var anotherMessage = "Hey";
anotherMessage += "How are you doing?";
console.log(anotherMessage);           // "HeyHow are you doing?"
```

is equivalent to

```
var anotherMessage = "Hey";
anotherMessage = anotherMessage + "How are you doing?";
console.log(anotherMessage);           // "HeyHow are you doing?"
```

Answer (score 0):

This would output `"HeyHow are you doing?"` as it says `x = x + y` and, for Strings in Javascript, '+' concatenates the two.

Note: The missing space between 'Hey' and 'How..'

Comment: @GameAlchemist Clearly I'm an amateur here looking for help. If this is a useless post, why bother commenting on it? Spare us your elitism and take your sarcasm elsewhere.

Comment: @Walt To be a fair to him: this question has been asked a thousand times, and basic syntax questions like this are often considered too simple/narrow for Stack Overflow. It will probably be closed, and maybe eventually deleted, and that will be appropriate (there's no benefit from dozens of identical duplicates). However, he is being an ass about it. It is practically impossible to search for `+=`, so you weren't likely to find previous posts. You're also relatively new so he shouldn't assume you know the standards. He should have *explained* them, but instead he decided to be an elitist dick.

Answer (score 0):

What happens, is called [concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation), ie assignment operator **+=** will "combine" old value and new value into one (by re-assigning the value to itself adding additional value).